# Applying the Stirling's formula on $\binom{n}{k}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

In class we used the following estimate:

$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}  = \frac{(1+\mathcal{O}(1))\sqrt{2 \pi n} \frac{n}{e}^n}{(1+\mathcal{O}(1))\sqrt{2 \pi k} \bigl(\frac{k}{e}\bigr)^k \sqrt{2 \pi (n-k)} \bigl(\frac{n-k}{e}\bigr)^{n-k}} $$

I realise that this stems from applying Stirlings formula to both the numerator and the denomiator of $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$, but it is not quite clear to me why we can do that. How can we be sure that this is indeed an upper bound?

Comment: This is *estimate* (not "upper bound") is correct only if both $k$ and $n-k$ tend to $\infty.$

Comment: There are Stirling formulas with inequalities valid for every $n$. Check out the Wiki link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation    You can apply this to the numerator and the denominator to obtain the desired inequalities.